# Visual studio is hanging when add a new dataset to RDLC report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I create a specific `report.rdlc` then i want to add new `datatable` to my report .

But after changing the data set ,trying to add new dataset to my report .

The visual studio is crashing every time and restart without adding the new dataset !

[image]

I search about this bug and According to [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1102922/visual-studio-crashes-when-trying-to-add-a-dataset-to-an-rdlc-report) ,it says :

> This is one of the oldest bugs in visual studio and it can easily
>   crash "all versions" of visual studio (which is VS.nET 2015 update 1
>   right now). it happens when you move your project to another directory
>   and report viewer component tries to open dataset schema from previous
>   location. in order to fix this open rdlc file with a text editor. look
>   for a property named "SchemaPath"and update the path of your dataset
>   file there .

---

I did this suggestion ,then clean the project and rebuild it but the same problem ! How to fix this problem ?

```
<rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:DataSetName>AnalysisDS1</rd:DataSetName>
        <rd:SchemaPath>N:\ProjData\FinanceList\FinanceList\Finance\App_Code\AnalysisDS1.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
        <rd:TableName>AnalysisDT1</rd:TableName>
        <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod />
        <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod />
        <rd:TableAdapterName />
</rd:DataSetInfo>
```

Comment: update to the Update 3 of VS2015 and look if it still crashes

Comment: In my case, I had some old unused dataSources laying around from older versions of a project. The said project didn't even used report viewer at that time. I deleted then and the problem was deleted too. Thanks for the tip from Microsoft forums!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no fixing to this bug in V.S until now, Hope **Microsoft** to fix this continuous problem .

---

***The Workaround :***

*I Add a new fresh project to my solution* ,then drag and drop my `RDLC` to my new project, then add a new data set ,finish my report and drag it again to its original project , and every thing goes okay .

Comment: I just ran into this problem with a report I needed to create. This was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Geezzz...Should have seen this question way back. HAd been wacking my brain for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This was occurring for me in VS2017. I was able to fix the issue by first deleting everything in the `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders of the project where the `.rdlc` is contained.

Specifically it seems like there's FileIOException being thrown when opening the Dataset Properties window and it seems like one or both of these files in the `/obj/` folder cannot be opened because they are being used by another process:

`DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences.cache`
`DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache`

I wasn't able to figure out why sometimes the `/bin/` needed to be cleared too, but better to be safe and just clear both.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happen for me. I just done following steps and works for me vs2015.

1. Build=> Clean Solution in debug mode.
2. Build=> Clean Solution in Release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove .vs or bin and obj still not working, but when i try to remove my datasource connection and add new connection it's worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me. I tried remove .vs folder and .suo file then clean and build in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I just suffered for a solid workday to fix this same issue, so I'll share in case it saves someone from loosing hair over this:

In my case, my dataset is fed by a stored procedure and by, trial and error, I found out that it was a left join that was causing my VS to freeze.

A few remarks:

- the stored procedure executed flawlessly on SSMS;
- Other stored procedures caused no issues in VS.

Cause: the foreign key in my T1 had a lot of nulls, so, even though SSMS didn't care and ran the join smoothly (in 1 sec), SSRS couldn't take it and kept freezing and crashing.

So, an example of the original code:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
        left join   table2 as t2    on  t1.FK= t2.PK
```

Solution:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
        left join   table2 as t2    on  t1.FK is not null   and t1.FK= t2.PK
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. To solve this problem there are two steps in my case those are given bellow:

**1st:** Open the the '**Event Viewer**' which is Default option of windows. In this 'Event Viewer' 
     you will find out the actual reason to occurs this problem.
**2nd:** Uninstall the '**Crystal Report**' from the control panel.After uninstall the crystal 
     report the problem is solved in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here...
open project directory=>Properties=>DataSources and delete all files from this folder... 
It works

Comment: This worked for us in VS2019 with a clean & build

Answer (score 0):

This bug was a pain to solve but in our projects we had a couple of solutions and/or workaround for this.

Usually you will get 2 not so helpful messages in the event viewer like this

First Message:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 15.9.28307.423, time
>   stamp: 0x5c5b5342 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x49e07264 Faulting process id: 0x3e4c Faulting application start
>   time: 0x01d5ab734dee5790 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   Faulting module path: unknown Report Id:
>   93b01c49-4490-41a4-a8db-142f6a99697a Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Second Message:

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.NullReferenceException at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.ProjectItemUtil.GetComplexElements(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.DesignUtil.GetVenusObjectDataSources(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema[],
>   System.IServiceProvider) at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.DataSetSynchronizer+d__11.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.DataSetSynchronizer+d__7.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.Dialogs.Pages.DataSetGeneralPage.LoadDataSources()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.Dialogs.Pages.DataSetGeneralPage.LoadData()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.Dialogs.DataSetDialog.OnLoad(System.EventArgs)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Solutions to resolve the issue:

1. For some of us, it was a DLL reference that was the issue microsoft.office.sharepoint.tools.dll. So the process was to look at the DLLs that were added to TFS recently and try to remove them one by one from the project and try to add dataset again. That solved the issue for most of our team.
2. Sometimes, Solution 1 is not enough, in my case I got the latest version from the fix from TFS but I was still having the issue. So the solution was to remove everything from the \Project\package\ folder, save all and rebuild all. That solved the issue for me. So package was still there even if the reference was gone.
3. This is a workaround but like people said here, you need to add a new project to your solution and create your rdlc report and dataset. This works fine but not so nice because you then need to copy your reports to the right Project after and change the content of .xsd (of the dataset) and the .rdlc file so that they point to the right path.
4. This one is pretty obvious but you need to check if the path of the dataset, schema, db connection are all pointing to the right path in the .xsd and .rdlc file.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be linked with this other question ?
[vs 2019 crashes without any error report when opening solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943615/vs-2019-crashes-without-any-error-report-when-opening-solution)

Repairing VS fixes the issue. Worth trying ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i needed to add a property to the dataset and crash was happened.
so the best way which i reached ,was changing xml file directly ;

for example, assume we want to add property called RegistrationDate :

1. open .rdlc file (the xml code not microsoft rdlc designer ) ;
   you can open path of rdlc file and open it with vs code or in visual studio, you can use compare in solution explorer

[Xml Code of Rdlc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtrEb.png)

2. if you already have property in rdlc file , find similar pattern and duplicate it and change the values :

[The pattern example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWt5c.png)

in my case ,i had **Code** property , and based on , i created RgistrationDate ;

so for any change in xml file T just find pattern and do it with code .
hope it's help