# vs 2019 crashes without any error report when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio

I have been working on a project (.Net core 3 if it matters) and suddenly VS closed. I used `VS2019 16.4.2` Version. 
Then every time i tried opening the project it crashed without any error on loading projects. 
I looked at the windows event viewer and there was not record of a crash.
I tried starting `devnev` with log and this is the last record which was recorded:

```
 <type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectPackage]</description>
<guid>{3347BEE8-D7A1-4082-95E4-38A439553CC2}</guid>
```

I upgraded to laterst version of VS2019 - `16.4.3`, Still the problem occurs.
From looking online for solution i tried 2 solutions which did not solved the problem:

1. Deleting .suo file
2. Deleting .user file

Last info: The problem also occurs when opening the project with VS2017. When opening other project i have (.NET Framework project) Its loaded successfully

Comment: Check if ActivityLog file has any info. The file can be found at the following path where version should be your visual studio version number
`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\ActivityLog.xml`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio is hanging when add a new dataset to RDLC report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077028/visual-studio-is-hanging-when-add-a-new-dataset-to-rdlc-report)

Answer (score 1):

I know, It is been a bit late but I encounter the same issue with VS2019. Updating it the latest version did not work. I repaired VS from VSInstaller and problem solved.

Comment: Repairing VS takes a long time but it fixed the issue